# Low Reynolds number assumption of Oseen type of flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum

Momentum balance part of the fluid dynamical equations for Oseen type of flow can be written as (in the reference frame of an object moving with $\mathbf{V}$),

\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{V}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{w} = -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} + \frac{\mu_{\text{l}}}{\rho} \nabla ^2 \mathbf{w}
\end{equation}

I am particularly interested in an approximate range of Reynolds number for which the Oseen equations make sense. [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oseen_equations) for example, mentions that it is applicable for very low Reynolds number. From which arguments such condition is derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take a look at the steady Navier-Stokes equations:

$$\nabla\cdot[\rho\vec{u}\otimes \vec{u}] = -{\nabla p} + \mu{\nabla^2}\vec{u} + \vec{f}$$

The way to obtain the Stokes equations used in microhydrodynamics is by assuming that the terms on the right hand side (forcing and/or viscous terms) are much bigger than the convective acceleration on the left hand side. One *approximate* way of quantifying that assumption is by also assuming the system has some characteristic densities/velocities/velocity gradients/viscosities/length scales and non-dimensionalizing the equation with these. Doing so gives you:

$$\text{Re}\left(\nabla\cdot[\rho^*\vec{u^*}\otimes \vec{u^*}]\right) = -{\nabla p^*} + {\nabla^2}\vec{u^*} + \vec{f^*}$$

where $\text{Re} = \frac{\rho U L}{\mu}$ is the familiar Reynolds number and the quantities defining it are the "characteristic" quantities of the system. Assuming the Reynolds number is tiny means that the left-hand side is negligible according to the approximation, and we don't have to care about it, netting the Stokes equations (back in dimensional form):

$$-{\nabla p} + \mu{\nabla^2}\vec{u} + \vec{f} = 0$$

Problem is, these assumption are pretty bad, and generate a massive amount of paradoxes and inconsistent results! Oseen's idea was to, rather than give up the convective acceleration term, to *linearize* it by saying the left hand-side terms can be approximated by

$$\nabla\cdot[\rho\vec{u}\otimes \vec{u}]\approx\nabla\cdot[\rho\vec{U}\otimes \vec{u}]$$

where $\vec{U}$ is the characteristic velocity of the system whose scalar form popped up in the Reynolds number; it's usually the velocity of whatever is causing the flow disturbance. This approximation straightforwardly generates the Oseen equations when you plug it into the steady Navier-Stokes equation:

$$\nabla\cdot[\rho\vec{U}\otimes \vec{u}] = -{\nabla p} + \mu{\nabla^2}\vec{u} + \vec{f}$$

In short, the Stokes equations are what you obtain when you neglect convective acceleration, and the Oseen equations are what you get if you try to linearize it.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I see the importance of Reynolds number in the formulation now.

Comment: how far does Oseen's approximation push the upper boundary on $Re$?

Comment: The Oseen approximation doesn't change at what $Re$ the system becomes undescribable by laminar flow, as that is -almost- always determined experimentally; what it does do is improve the accuracy of the solutions in the low-$Re$ regime.